# CSS, express and bootstrap : overflow and margin error

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, express

I stack two circles over an image, using the position and overflow properties. 
It works fine but I have the circle running over the image on left and right (not top and left.

Here is the image : [Circle overflowing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sL7AD.png)

Here is the CSS.

```
.mainContainer {
  background-color: #A6A4AA
}

.targetImage {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border: solid medium #2C3756;
    border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
    background-color: #A6A4AA;
    position: relative;
}

#targetCol {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;

}

.impact, .ajustement {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #dc022e;
  border-radius: 100%;
  opacity: 0.75;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border: solid medium #2C3756;

}

.ajustement {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

The code source (ejs+bootstrap) : the row is a child of mainContainer

```
<div class="row">    <!-- Row : target            -->
  <div class= "col-xs-12" id="targetCol">
    <img id="target" class="targetImage"></img>
    <div id="ajustement" class="ajustement"></div>
    <div id="impact" class="impact"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I draw my circles into the images only, without running out the border ?

Here is what I would like : [image: What I would like]

Comment: Can you share an image sample, that where you want that circle?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @kravisingh. I did add the image in the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you looking something like this:

```css
 body{
   margin: 0;
   background-color: #A6A4AA
}
 .mainContainer {
   background-color: #A6A4AA;
   margin: 15px auto;
   width: 98%;
}

.targetImage {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;    
    border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
    background: #A6A4AA;
    position: relative;
}

#targetCol {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  border: 3px solid #2C3756;
  line-height: 0;
  border-radius: 12px;

}

.impact, .ajustement {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #dc022e;
  border-radius: 100%;
  opacity: 0.75;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border: 3px solid #2C3756;
  left: -45%;
  top: -78px;
  height: calc(100% + 78px);
}
.impact{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-color: #000;
  left: 10%;
  top: 10%;
}

.ajustement {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainContainer">
<div class="row">    <!-- Row : target            -->
  <div class= "col-xs-12" id="targetCol">
    <img id="target" class="targetImage" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/aa/Papageitaucher_Fratercula_arctica.jpg/800px-Papageitaucher_Fratercula_arctica.jpg">
    <div id="ajustement" class="ajustement"></div>
    <div id="impact" class="impact"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```